# how does the order function break ties in R?

Tags: r

I've read most of the similar questions here, but I'm still having a hard time understanding how passing arguments in the order function break ties.

The example introduced in the R documentation shows that :

```
order(x <- c(1,1,3:1,1:4,3), y <- c(9,9:1), z <- c(2,1:9))
```

returns

```
[1]  6  5  2  1  7  4 10  8  3  9
```

However, what does it mean when y is 'breaking ties' of x, and z 'breaking ties' of y? the x vector is:

```
[1] 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 3
```

and the y vector is:

```
[1] 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Also, if I eliminate z from the first function,

```
order(x <- c(1,1,3:1,1:4,3), y <- c(9,9:1))
```

it returns :

```
[1]  6  5  1  2  7  4 10  8  3  9
```

so I'm unclear how the numbers in the y vector are relevant with ordering the four 1s, the two 2s, and the three 3s in x. I would very much appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: From [`?order`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html): *In the case of ties in the first vector, values in the second are used to break the ties.  If the values are still tied, values in the later arguments are used to break the tie*. So when there are ties in the first, it goes to the second; if there are no ties in the first, the second is not referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at

```
idx <- order(x <- c(1,1,3:1,1:4,3), y <- c(9,9:1), z <- c(2,1:9))
idx;
#[1]  6  5  2  1  7  4 10  8  3  9
```

First thing to note is that

```
x[idx]
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

So `idx` orders entries in `x` from smallest to largest values.

Values in `y` and `z` affect how `order` treats ties in `x`.

Take entries `x[5] = 1` and `x[6] = 1`. Since there is a tie here, `order` looks up entries at the corresponding positions in `y`, i.e. `y[5] = 6` and `y[6] = 5`. Since `y[6] < y[5]`, the entries in `x` are sorted `x[6] < x[5]`.

If there is a tie in `y` as well, `order` will look up entries in the next vector `z`. This happens for `x[1] = 1` and `x[2] = 2`, where both `y[1] = 9` and `y[2] = 9`. Here `z` breaks the tie because `z[2] = 1 < z[1] = 2` and therefore `x[2] < x[1]`.

Comment: I understand now exactly. Thank you so much for the thorough answer!       @MauritsEvers